# Transitive Class

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Prove that every nonempty transitive class has $\emptyset$ as a member.

A class is transitive if each of its members is a subset of it. 
i.e. if t $\in$ T then t $\subseteq$ T.

This is what I have so far-
Assume T is a nonempty transitive class. We want to show that $\emptyset$ $\in$ T. By the definition of transitive, we know that if $\emptyset$ $\in$ T then $\emptyset$ $\subseteq$ T.

I want to use the Axiom of Regularity to finish the proof but can't figure it out exactly. The Axiom of Regularity states that every nonempty set has a member that is disjoint from it. 
i.e. there is no set X whose members are all nonempty subsets of X

Answer (score 1):

This is just a matter of definition chasing.

Given $T$, the Axiom of Regularity gives us an $A\in T$ that is disjoint from $T$.

Suppose $a$ is an element of $A$. Because $A$ is disjoint from $T$, $a$ is not an element of $T$. But because $T$ is transitive, $A$ is a subset of $T$, so $a$, being an element of $A$, is also an element of $T$. So $a$ is simultaneously a member of $T$ and not a member of $T$. This is impossible, and the only way out is to conclude that $A$ *has no elements*. In other words $A=\varnothing$, and we already know that $A\in T$.

Comment: To put it a tiny bit more concisely: By Regularity, there is some $A\in T$ such that $A\cap T=\emptyset$. Since $T$ is transitive, $A\subseteq T$, so $A=A\cap T=\emptyset$, i.e., $\emptyset=A\in T$. On the other hand, you might have expanded a bit on how you handle the case where $T$ is a proper class, seeing as the usual formulation of the Axiom of Regularity only talks about sets, I believe. Something with transitive closure, I guess?

Comment: @bof: Oops, I missed the part of the question where $T$ could be a proper class.